# How to position text on same line in Div?

Tags: html, asp.net, asprepeater, nowrap

I want to position text in a div so that the line of text stays on the same line and doesn't wrap onto multiple lines.

What I have tried is adding the `nwrp` property to the div, by adding some sample text but as shown in the screenshot below the text wraps onto multiple lines:

```
<div runat="server" id="OfferStatusString" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nwrp"><p><strong>This text is strong, testing that the text doesn't wrap to the next line using nwrp property of bootstrap. Text should stay on the same line on the window</strong>.</p></div>
```

[image: text wrapping]

Does anyone know how to specify the div text positioning to stay on the same line?

This div is contained within a Repeater control as shown below:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterApplicationItems" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeaterApplicationItems_ItemDataBound" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="row applicationitems mrgn lhgt">

                                        <div runat="server" id="OfferStatusString" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nwrp"><strong><%# (string)Eval("ApplicationItemStatusString").ToString() %></strong></div>


                                    </div>
                               </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: all text in one line?

Comment: yes, I want the text to show on one line and not wrap onto multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So use this:**

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/99zerbkn/)

Comment: So the following will work? My syntax seems different to your example:


                                        `<div runat="server" id="OfferStatusString" overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nwrp"><strong><%# (string)Eval("ApplicationItemStatusString").ToString() %></strong></div>`

Comment: use overflow and white-space in style tag

Comment: Okay I've added a style tag to the definition but get errors within the tag stating that "missing a pseudo class name". Is there a mistake in my div code?  


                                        `<div runat="server" id="OfferStatusString" <style>overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;</style>  class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nwrp"><strong><%# (string)Eval("ApplicationItemStatusString").ToString() %></strong></div>`

Comment: <div runat="server" id="OfferStatusString" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nwrp"><strong><%# (string)Eval("ApplicationItemStatusString").ToString() %></strong>

Comment: Thanks that was the solution.